# занести значения в value

Tags: javascript, html

Как заносить значения value в поле input?

Ребята, HELP! У меня есть калькулятор, который рассчитывает значения в div id ="result". Мне надо, чтобы он эти значения также заносил в value в input name="result". Как это можно сделать?

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">Итого:</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">Итого:</div>
<div class="total" style="display: inline-block;" id="result">0</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">рублей</div>
</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="сюда нужно занести значения" />
```

Comment: Добавьте id для вашего input, и вместе с присвоением в блок result, добавляйте и в input. Как-то так `document.getElementById('my-input').value = ` и значение вашего калькулятора

Comment: к сожалению, новичок в js. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: у меня значения хранит в innerHTML. Как вытащить и занести в input value?

Comment: А всё! Получилось!))

Answer (score 0):

Изменил тип `input` для наглядности. Также можно опустить переменную `result` и сразу напрямую присваивать значения.

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('my-input').value = result;
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;">Итого:</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">Итого:</div>
<div class="total" style="display: inline-block;" id="result">30</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">рублей</div>
<input type="text" name="result" id="my-input" value="сюда нужно занести значения" />
```